# Undeploy API from Apigee X Environment of type "archive"

Tags: api, environment, archive, apigee, undeploy

Does anyone have an idea how to "undeploy" an API proxy from an "archive" type Apigee-x environment? It seems like it can't be done from the Apigee UI, it throws an error:
"This operation is not supported. The Environment DeploymentType is ARCHIVE. The required Environment DeploymentType is PROXY".
The environment type can't be changed. The available CLI commands are "delete", "deploy", "describe", "list", "update" (no "undeploy" command found), "delete" doesn't work as it can't delete an active deployment. The final goal is to be able to delete the environment, which requires to remove/undeploy all API proxies from it first.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The "undeploy" feature I was looking for is not included in the current Apigee-x release. On the Apigee community, Google staff [stated](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/Undeploy-API-Proxy-from-Apigee-X-Environment-of-type-quot/m-p/476990#M72488) that they are looking into implementing it at some point. Until then there is a workaround, where one can deploy an archive with no deployments defined to the environment. Once this is done the Proxy is "undeployed" and the environment could be deleted. Here is the step-by-step [process](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/deploy/manage-archive-deployments#delete-archive-environments) of doing it.